# PowerShell to remove built-in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: windows-8, powershell

There are the PowerShell commands `Get-AppxPackage` and `Remove-AppxPackage` that allow you to remove Metro apps. However, they don't seem to show the built-in apps.

I don't use Mail, People, Messaging, Calendar, News, Sports, and some other built-in apps.

Is there any way I can write a script to uninstall these instead of manually right-clicking on each one?

Comment: Seriously, I don't think you should bother. How many built-in apps are there? Less than 15?

Comment: @Ariane It doesn't matter if it makes sense for anybody. Its about is it possible.

Comment: I understand. Or uhm, if you really can't find anything and really want to automate this, perhaps you can go with a sort of script that would control your mouse and do the clicks at lightning speed. Just an idea.

Comment: @Ariane There are 1.5GB worth of them on my SSD... that's a clean install, although I did run some of them a couple of times out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a script here:

**Removing Built-in Applications from Windows 8**
http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2012/10/26/removing-built-in-applications-from-windows-8.aspx

Here is also a script to delete Apps:

**Remove Windows Store apps in Windows 8**
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Windows-Store-Apps-a00ef4a4

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
```

all apps gone!