# How do we uninstall windows store apps under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, skype, uninstall

I'm having a heck of a time uninstalling some Windows Store apps. It has become a pain point because the operating system is basically lying to me. Its telling me it has uninstalled the app and then it is surreptitiously running the app.

For example, Microsoft changed the security architecture of Skype to allow proxying and interception. I want nothing to do with the app because Microsoft's actions disgusts me. I used PowerShell and then DISM to remove Skype. PowerShell succeeds, but [DISM fails with Error 87](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/dism-cleanup-image-not-working/e4611720-6add-4040-be9f-40516369d629), which appears to mean it has already been removed.

However, after a reboot, it appears Microsoft retained it and executes it:

[image]

How do we uninstall windows store apps under Windows 10?

---

Obviously, answers to questions like [How to fully uninstall a Windows Store app?](https://superuser.com/q/533170/173513) are not working. Apparently, something has changed from Windows 8 to Windows 10.

Comment: [Those commands should work.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4689-apps-uninstall-windows-10-a.html#option3).  Be sure you are removing the correct package.  I presume after you removed the package, you restarted the machine, Windows Universal Apps work differently then Win32 applications.

Comment: [Additional Information](http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/31142-how-do-i-shut-down-skypehost-exe.html).  [Couple more steps](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2782527/remove-skype-windows.html) should be done.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, the machine has been restarted. The Process Explorer image was snapped after a remove/reboot cycle.

Comment: @Ramhound - out of curiosity, why do you even visit my questions? You appear to down vote all of them even when I attempt to explain why I am doing what I am doing. And more humorously, you said some thing about me down-voting you. I rarely down-vote, and I don't ever recall casting such a vote on you. (The down-votes concern me because it could detract visitiors and possible answers).

Comment: [I actually do find some of your questions to be well written and helpful](http://superuser.com/questions/1006721/determine-tls-certificate-details-with-microsoft-edge).  I provide my initial thoughts, my desire is that from those initial thoughts either it helps you formulate your own answer to your question, or I get enough information to answer the question myself.